# How to open different activity while clicking push notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

In my app I use a third party SDK for chat, when I receive a chat it will come in push notification. The thing I need is while I clicking the push notification it should be protected by password (separate activity) and then once the password is correct it should open the chat page(third party SDK).
Here is my code

```
public GcmIntentService() {
    super(Library.SENDER_ID);
}

public static final String TAG = "XXX";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // Post notification of received message.


            boolean handled = MXNotificationManager.preProcessMXNotification(getApplicationContext(), intent);
            if (handled) {
                // This is a moxtra message and it will be handled by moxtra
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(MXNotificationManager.MOXTRA_MESSAGE_SHOW_NOTIFICATION, false)) {
                    String title = intent.getStringExtra(MXNotificationManager.MOXTRA_MESSAGE_TITLE_TEXT);
                    if (intent.hasExtra(MXNotificationManager.MOXTRA_MESSAGE_ALERT_SOUND)) {
                        String soundUrl = intent.getStringExtra(MXNotificationManager.MOXTRA_MESSAGE_ALERT_SOUND);
                        Log.d(TAG, "soundUrl = " + soundUrl);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(soundUrl);
                        sendMoxtraNotification(title, uri, intent);

                    } else {
                        sendMoxtraNotification(title, intent);
                    }
                }
            }else {
                // Not a moxtra message and app should handle it.
                Log.i(TAG, "App should handle it.");

            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }

    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}


private void sendMoxtraNotification(String msg, Intent intent) {
    sendMoxtraNotification(msg, null, intent);
}

private void sendMoxtraNotification(String msg, Uri uri, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got notification: msg = " + msg + ", uri = " + uri);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);




   PendingIntent contentIntent = MXNotificationManager.getMXNotificationIntent(this, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(getApplicationInfo().labelRes))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    if (uri != null) {
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
    }

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
 mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to pass the PendingIntent from moxtra to your Password Activity. And in the notification, you have to send your PendingIntent to bring up the Password Activity. And in your password activity, if user enter the correct password, you can send the PendingIntent from moxtra.

Here is the code snippet to construct your PendingIntent:

```
    private void sendMoxtraNotification(String msg, Uri uri, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got notification: msg = " + msg + ", uri = " + uri);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent moxtraContentIntent = MXNotificationManager.getMXNotificationIntent(this, intent, 0);

    Intent passwordActivityIntent = new Intent(this, PasswordActivity.class);
    passwordActivityIntent.putExtra("PendingIntent", moxtraContentIntent);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, passwordActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(getApplicationInfo().labelRes))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    if (uri != null) {
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
    }

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And when user enter the correct password, you have to:

```
PendingIntent intent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("PendingIntent");
try {
    intent.send();
} catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like this

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);

//        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", msg);

        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I have tried, but how come it will enter the MXNotificationManager.getMXNotificationIntent

Comment: Could you please explain, I am quite new to android.

Comment: just create your own Notification when you receive the message and put all necessary data in intent and start your password activity on notification click and when user confirms the password then open the chat activity and pass all data to that activity...

Comment: That is where the issue, I cant able to open the chat activity directly through the password activity because the third party SDK only can be accessed through the pending intent with their own method "PendingIntent contentIntent = MXNotificationManager.getMXNotificationIntent", you can study the above code. Thats where I stuck